# Can't reproduce bootstrap regression result matlab

Tags: matlab, regression, bootstrapping, seed

I have a simple linear regression. I want to obtain the standard errors of this regression by bootstrap. I want to start by obtaining the betas of the regression from the bootstrap, because i need to compute other quantities with those betas as well.

I am running the following code in matlab.

beta_bootstr=bootstrp(k,@(bootr)regress(RES.yhat+bootr,XX),r);

My problem is simple: every time I run this code I get a different result.

I tried to add a seed before:

rng('default')

beta_bootstr=bootstrp(k,@(bootr)regress(RES.yhat+bootr,XX),r);

But it does nothing.

How can I make sure the results can be replicated? Thank you.

Nvm i solved it- i needed to reset(stream).

Comment: This is something else I tried and didn't work
stream = RandStream('mrg32k3a', 'Seed', 1);
beta_bootstr=bootstrp(k,@(bootr)regress(RES.yhat+bootr,XX),r, 'Options',statset( 'Streams', stream, 'UseSubstreams',true))